# Doctrine does not update a simple array type field

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

### Short Story (Edit)

It is possible to store an array instead of a mapped association. In Symfony2, this is fairly easy using the [collection Field Type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html). For example, using this technique, you could store an array of text fields that populate an array events field. However, to update an array, there is a trick, and this trick is beautifully explained by @Vadim Ashikhman in the accepted answer.

### Long Story

Sometimes it is useful and more efficient to store an array instead of a mapped association. However, once created, it remains complicated to update this Array if the size of that array does not change?

Many people have a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11084209/how-to-force-doctrine-to-update-array-type-fields) but nobody found a proper solution to this problem.

[image: Store an array]

A team can organise many events. These events are simply stored within an array using Doctrine instead of using a OneToMany association. Therefore, the entity Event is not mapped with Doctrine.

### Entity Event (not mapped with Doctrine)

```
<?php

namespace Acme\TestBundle\Entity;

...

class Event
{

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $name;

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }


}
```

### Entity Team

```
<?php

namespace Acme\TestBundle\Entity;

...

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * @ORM\Table(name="teams")  
 */
class Team 
{

/**
     * @ORM\Column(type="array")
     * @var array
     */
    protected $events;


    public function addEvent($event)
    {
        if (!in_array($event, $this->events, true)) {
            $this->events[] = $event;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeEvent($event)
    {
        if (false !== $key = array_search($event, $this->events, true)) {
            unset($this->events[$key]);
            $this->events = array_values($this->events);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEvents()
    {
        return $this->events;
    }

    public function setEvents(array $events)
    {
        $this->events = array();

        foreach ($events as $event) {
            $this->addEvent($event);
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

### Event Form

```
<?php
namespace Acme\TestBundle\Form\Type;

...

class EventType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

        $builder->add('name', 'text');
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\TestBundle\Entity\Event',
            'cascade_validation' => true,
        ));
    }

    ...
}
```

### Team Form

```
<?php

namespace Acme\TestBundle\Form\Type;

...

class TeamType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

        $builder->add('events','collection', array(
            'type' => new EventType(),
            'allow_add'   => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'prototype' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
            'options' => array('data_class' => 'Acme\TestBundle\Entity\Event'),
            )
        );

    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\TestBundle\Entity\Team',
        ));
    }
    ...

}
```

### The Controller

```
/**
 * Update a team
 *
 * @Route("update/{team_id}", name="updateTeamFromId")
 * @Template("AcmeTestBundle:Team:teamUpdate.html.twig")
 */
public function updateTeamAction($team_id, Request $request)
{

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $repository= $em->getRepository('AcmeTestBundle:Team');

    $team_to_update = $repository->find($team_id);

    $form = $this->createForm(new teamType(), $team_to_update);

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST')
    {
        $form->bind($request);

        if ($form->isValid()){

            $em->persist($team_to_update);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('homepage'))  ;
        }
    }

    return array(
    'form' => $form->createView(),
    'team_id' => $team_id,
    );

}
```

Comment: It could be an error of "owning side" and "inversed side". Could you paste us the associations between those entities?

Comment: Thanks @DonCallisto, but I am storing the events in an array. There is no association. The entities are entirely posted here. Thanks fery much for your help

Comment: Can you add a `var_dump($team_to_update->getEvents());` and a `var_dump($form->getData()->getEvents());`inside the `if ($form->isValid()) { .. }` block and show the output of both

Comment: Yep, the crazy thing is that they are the same and contain the updated values! `$team_to_update` contains the correct values before being persisted, but because the size of the array does not change, the values are not modified by doctrine. This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13227658/doctrine-does-not-update-a-simple-array-type-field) recommends to change the tracking policies of Doctrine, but does not seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this inside the controller:

```
public function updateTeamAction($team_id, Request $request)
{

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $repository= $em->getRepository('AcmeTestBundle:Team');

    $team_to_update = $repository->find($team_id);

    $form = $this->createForm(new teamType(), $team_to_update);

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST')
    {
        $form->bind($request);

        if ($form->isValid()){
            $events = $team_to_update->getEvents();
            foreach($events as $key => $value){
                $team_to_update->removeEvent($key);
            }
            $em->flush();
            $team_to_update->setEvents($events);
            $em->persist($team_to_update);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('homepage'))  ;
        }
    }

    return array(
    'form' => $form->createView(),
    'team_id' => $team_id,
    );

}
```

There is probably a beter way to do this and i know this isnt a nice way to do it but till you (or someone else) finds that solution you can use this as a temporary fix.

Comment: I see, but with your issue your not updating and object in an array but a string value so I guess `clone` doesn't work for you as it can't be used for strings (asfar as I know)?

Comment: It is possible like this: `$i=0; foreach ($events as $event){ $events[$i] = clone $event; $i++;}`