# Type of choice field Symfony2

Tags: symfony, checkbox, doctrine

I try to save values of one - three checkboxes in field category in database, but i get the error :

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/OnTheWay/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Statement.php line 120
```

The field:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $category;
```

Get & Set:

```
    /**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getCategory()
{
    return $this->category;
}

/**
 * @param $category
 */
public function setCategory($category)
{
    $this->category[] = $category;
}
```

Profile type:

```
 namespace Vputi\UserBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class ProfileType extends  AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('fio');
        $builder->add('birthDate', null, array('widget' => 'single_text'));
        $builder->add('file');
        $builder->add('yearOnRoad');
        $builder->add('telephone');
        $builder->add('contactMail');
        $builder->add('role', 'choice', array('choices' => array(1 => 'За рулем') ,'expanded'=>true, 'multiple' => true,));
        $builder->add('category', 'choice', array(
            'choices'  => array('A' => 'Категория А', 'B' => 'Категория B', 'C' => 'Категория C',),
            'expanded' => true,
            'multiple' => true,
        ));
    }
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' =>'Vputi\UserBundle\Entity\Profile',
            'cascade_validation' => true,
        ));
    }
 }
```

Here is my form type, I hope you help me, and iam ommit getName() method.

Comment: Could you post your `Entity` definition code?

Comment: i added code, i think problem in annotations and in set method....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `$category` is defined as a `string` but you're using it like an `array`.

The solution depends on exactly what you want to accomplish. If you want it to be mapped as an `array` you have to do this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="array", nullable=true)
 */
private $category;
```

When using `Doctrine`'s `array` type, make sure you take this into account: [How to force Doctrine to update array type fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11084209/how-to-force-doctrine-to-update-array-type-fields)

Comment: thats hepl on registration, but i get another problem on edit profile:
`Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/OnTheWay/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/ChoiceList/ChoiceList.php line 462`

Comment: Can you post your `Type`? I'll update my answer based on that.

Comment: yes. but i dont get any results, problem still here